# How to tell MathJax to use an alternative syntax for subscripts?

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax

I have a problem with my blog. When writing posts I can also add math using MathJax. I also have a little markup language of mine where I can handle italic and bold text. It happens that the syntax for italic collides with the MathJax one's for subscript.

So, if I write in a port the following:

```
My cat was doing this strange sound: _Prrrrrr_.
```

The text between underscores is redered with a span tag using italic style.

But in MathJax using underscores means having subscripts. Sometimes I have problems of course. The point is that first my markup language is handled, then Mathjax can run.

Is there a way to tell MathJax to make subscripts and superscripts without using underscores but an alternative syntax?

Thankyou

Comment: Which syntax gets through your custom markup parser?

Comment: When in a math expression like $S(a_1,a_2,a_3)$. The first two underscores are considered by my markup language like italic and it is substituted with <span style="...">1,a</span> and after this MathJax runs... Of course MathJax will not be able to render this thing properly

Comment: So, you rather need to change your markup language to recognize math expression, than to make MathJax detect spans as underscores...

Comment: It is not good... I added math functionality now,,, I have so many posts already using this syntax... it s better to add an alternative syntax in MathJax... really is it that difficult to add a new environment or something???

Comment: Do your old post already use MathJax-syntax? If no, it will be no problem changing your markup parser.

Comment: The point is that I need to edit them as well to add some math... It would be better just adding some sort of alternative syntax to MathJax... My question is about this, I already though about changing the markup syntax, but here i wanne see if I can act on MathJax instead...

Comment: I don't think so. I'm quite sure MathJax does not detect math across span elements, so you will need to replace them. Changing your markup parser to detect Math expressions and don't apply underscore replacements will be much easier - or do you need subscript tags inside math?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. Using Macros as described here: [Configure Tex in MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/options/TeX.html#configure-tex).
By setting something like this:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({TeX: {Macros:{subscript:['_{#1}',1],superscript:['^{#1}',1]}}});
```

The system (MathJax) will substitute this stuff with the underscore  and then parse it, my problem is actually solved like this!

Comment: This method seems do not copy with the text $x_\mu$ and $y_\mu$ properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found escaping the underscores with a backslash helped, like this:

```
...strange sound: \_Prrrrrr\_.
```

But this did cause some parsers to render things incorrectly.

However, if you also define '`\_`' as a macro which just outputs '`_`', then it all seems to work.

To do this in MathJax:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({TeX: {Macros: { '\_': ['_'] }}, /* rest of config here... */ });
```

To do this in Katex, I changed `katex_config.js` to:

```
module.exports = {
  macros: { '\\_': '_' }
}
```